# Combining and modifying two data arrays into a single array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Consider this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygdKA/4/) example. In this example I want the var data array

```
[4,3],
[4,4],
[6, 6],
[6, 7],
[7,8],
[7,9],
[8,10],
[8,11]
```

to be modified as

```
 [4,3,4],
 [6,6,7],
 [7,8,9],
 [8,10,11]
```

I want the [X,Y] field to be modified to [X,Y1,Y2]. How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Original data
var data = [[4,3],
[4,4],
[6, 6],
[6, 7],
[7,8],
[7,9],
[8,10],
[8,11]]

//Group data by x coordinate in an object
var intermediate = {};

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    intermediate [data[i][0]] = (intermediate [data[i][0]] || []).concat(data[i][1]);
}

//Convert intermediate object to array
var result = [];

for(var i in intermediate){
        result.push([parseInt(i)].concat(intermediate[i]));
}
```

**edit:** to change the data the other way around:

```
var data = [[4,3,4],[6,6,7],[7,8,9],[8,10,11]];
var result = [];

data.forEach(function(row){
    row.slice(1).forEach(function(cell){
        result.push([row[0], cell]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Borre - I want the var data value to be declared as [4,3,4], [6,6,7], [7,8,9], [8,10,11] instead of [4,3], [4,4], [6, 6], [6, 7], [7,8], [7,9], [8,10], [8,11]

Comment: Do you mean you want to transform the data the other way around?

Comment: Bore-Yes and it should reflect on the chart.

Comment: I added the reverse operation to my answer

Comment: Borre- I have a changed output [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ygdKA/7/) the output should remain the same as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygdKA/4/). Only the array declartion in var data should change

Comment: Well off course you now need to plot the result array, which contains the correct values, not the data array. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ygdKA/8/

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = [];
var arr = [[4,3], [4,4],[6, 6],[6, 7],[7,8],[7,9],[8,10],[8,11]];
for(var i = 0;i< arr.length;i+=2){
    result.push([arr[i][0], arr[i][1], arr[i+1][1]])
}
```

Comment: Romko - I want the var data value to be declared as [4,3,4],
 [6,6,7],
 [7,8,9],
 [8,10,11] instead of [4,3],
[4,4],
[6, 6],
[6, 7],
[7,8],
[7,9],
[8,10],
[8,11] in the example